# Multiple calls to jQuery.noConflict() on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

We've developed a page with whole bunch of functionality implemented as separate components.
The jQuery itself is included into the page header only once.
But each component has exact the same piece of javascript code:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Could these multiple calls to jquery's noconflict on the same page and assigning the result to the same variable create some problems (e.g. with using plugins) ? Is it acceptable ? I would expect it to work as a singleton, i.e. always returning reference to the same internal object and no matter what.
Thanks in advance for your help, folks!

Comment: Sounds like you should use a better pattern for the scripts. Look how jQuery plug-ins are written.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.

In your case, multiple calls should be no harm, as it is an idempotent function.

In case you plan to include such components in an unknown environment, it is a safe practice to call it before proceeding.

---

Consider using a [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) in order to bind it to your context:

```
(function($){
  // here $ will be the global, common jQuery object you passed as an argument
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok, great. How about rewriting the same global variable in each component, i.e. j$. Could be any problems with this, if for instance some plugins are used in different components ?

Comment: I would back my modules in [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), for instance, so each would have a proper, independent dependency set. Or look at my edit.